# Correct Quick Release Hub Size for Kickr trainer and Merida Road Bike?

Tags: road-bike, trainer, wahoo

This is a very specific question, which I hope is OK here.

I just bought a Kickr trainer, V5 (2020).  I want to know what [Quick Release Hub size](https://support.wahoofitness.com/hc/en-us/articles/204281814-Selecting-Correct-Hub-Width-130mm-or-135mm-) (130mm or 135mm) to choose for my Merida Scultura 100 (2022).  I'm not sure how to read the [Merida specs](https://www.merida-bikes.com/en/bike/3092/scultura-rim-100) to determine this -- I don't see anything specific there that looks around 130 or 135mm.

Wahoo says most road bikes use 130mm, but I just want to check to make sure.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec you linked to says that the rear hub is 130mm wide:

```
HUBS

Road seal bearing
100x9mm width front hub
24 spoke holes
130x9mm width rear hub <==
28 spoke holes
```

This will be the same for all frame sizes.

Comment: Thanks -- that's under HUBS.  I hadn't thought to look there!  However, one thing I also found (under "FRAME SCULTURA LITE BSA") was "material: aluminium, 700x25C max. wheelsize, 100x9/ 135x9mm axle standard, BSA bottom bracket standard".  Does the 135x9 indicate something?

Comment: That is weird indeed. You could mail Merida and ask them. Or if you already have the bike: measure